# what is mime format for url for nfc in android?

Tags: android, nfc, ndef

so, i have an NFC project, i use "text/x-vcard" and "text/plain" for text type and vcard type in my nfc writer.

on text type, the reader will read it and show the text
on vcard type, the reader will read it and open contact application

```
private NdefMessage getNoteAsNdef() {
    byte[] textBytes = mNote.getText().toString().getBytes();
    NdefRecord textRecord = new NdefRecord(NdefRecord.TNF_MIME_MEDIA, "text/uri-list".getBytes(),
            new byte[] {}, textBytes);
    return new NdefMessage(new NdefRecord[] {
        textRecord
    });
```

i tried for url type, i'm using "text/uri-list" and when i read it using the reader, nothing happen and it won't jump to my phone browser

so what i supposed to do when anything like this happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creating a `NdefRecord` with an URL which opens in the browser should work this way:

```
NdefRecord rtdUriRecord1 = NdefRecord.createUri("http://example.com");
```

**References:**

- [NdefRecord.createUri() example](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/nfc/nfc.html#well-known-uri)
- [Creating Common Types of NDEF Records](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/nfc/nfc.html#creating-records)

Comment: thanks, it worked, when i read it, it goes to web browser, but, on the web browser, what URL i write in textbox doesn't match for what in browser, is there something i need to add?